# How to use LIST_SORT function in SML/NJ?

Tags: functional-programming, smlnj, ml

I don't get how to use properly the function to sort a list in SML/NJ (Standard ML of New Jersey).

This is the manual : [here](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/listsort.html)

make a use case example, 
e.g. sort ([1,9,3,4]); in order to get [1,3,4,9].

Comment: The link op gave doesn't work. Here is the link: http://www.kb.ecei.tohoku.ac.jp/~sumii/class/proenb2012/library/smlnj/Manual/listsort.html#SIG:LIST_SORT.sort:VAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very briefly, following is the syntax:

```
ListMergeSort.sort (fn(x,y)=> x>y) [3,5,6,7,4,3,7,9,1,2,3];
```

**Explanation:**
ListMergeSort: Because that is the structure provided as it comes in the documentation:

> **Synopsis**
>
> `signature LIST_SORT`
>
> `structure ListMergeSort : LIST_SORT`
>
> The LIST_SORT signature specifies an interface for the applicative sorting of lists.

Thereafter, the sort function requires two parameters as is evident from the interface:

```
val sort : (('a * 'a) -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

1. a function that accepts two parameters and returns a `boolean`: `(('a * 'a) -> bool)`
   This is exemplified by the anonymous function I defined on the fly:

   `fn(x,y)=> x>y`

It accepts two parameters and it returns a `boolean`. These two parameters are provided by the `sort` function who will pass in the elements of the list to be sorted.

2. a list that requires to be sorted, e.g.: [3,5,6,7,4,3,7,9,1,2,3]